# Using Espresso For Functional Testing of Android Application

Tags: junit4, android-espresso

We are planning to build a functional automation testing framework for testing an android app. After some research, I started getting a feeling that Espresso is not very suitable for functional and end to end App testing since it uses JUnit 4 Runner. Below are some limitations of JUnit4 I came across.

- JUnit4 Runner is unable to define a test order. Hence, it is not suitable for testing a scenario in which multiple tests are performed one after another.
- Junit4 Runner cannot group my tests so I cannot categorize my tests  (for example: sanity/regressions).
- @BeforeSuite, @AfterSuite, @BeforeTest,@AfterTest annotations are present. These become very important for setting up and flushing out common resources. Usage is quite heavy in functional tests.

Looking for your opinions to suggest if there is a clean way to implement functional tests using Espresso.

Answer (score 0):

I've integrated [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#java) on the project I work on.

Some good articles here:

[The evolution journey of Android GUI testing](https://medium.com/@sebaslogen/the-evolution-journey-of-android-gui-testing-f65005f7ced8)

[Into the Belly of the Beast: UI Testing an Android App with Cucumber and Espresso](https://medium.com/@Alex_Fogleman/into-the-belly-of-the-beast-ui-testing-an-android-app-with-cucumber-and-espresso-4a65ae61539a)

With Cucumber:

- you solve the test order matter;
- you can make use of [tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags) to organise your test suites;
- you can also use [hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) to setUp or tearDown your test environment.